# ML model gives less accuracy when Image is resized automatically compared to manually by photoshop

Tags: java, android-studio, machine-learning, image-processing, tensorflow-lite

I am building an App that detects pneumonia cases using frontal chest X-ray Images. I have build a benchmark test into the app to ensure everything is working properly.

Now the problem is when I insert test case Images as it is and let the app resize them to required size by the model(224x224) the benchmark gives less accuracy, But when I manually resized them in photoshop by stretching and rescaling images to fit a canvas of 224x224 pixel then uploading, It gives higher accuracy.

The code is not changed in both scenario just the test cases of the same images

1. original images
2. resized images(224x224)

the code of image preprocessing is as:

```
public ByteBuffer preProcessImage(Bitmap bitmap){


        ImageProcessor imageProcessor = new ImageProcessor.Builder()
                .add(new ResizeOp(224, 224, ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR)).add(new DequantizeOp(0, 1/255.0f)).build();
        TensorImage tensorImage = new TensorImage(DataType.FLOAT32);
        tensorImage.load(bitmap);
        tensorImage = imageProcessor.process(tensorImage);

        ByteBuffer imageBuffer = tensorImage.getBuffer();


        return imageBuffer;

    }
```

The result after both approach (Image):

[result comparison Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlfrQ.jpg)

debug code format in lower part of screenshot is

> :{trueLabel} {predictedLabel} {model output}:

Please Help me resolve this as in running app, Images will be uploaded of original size.

Comment: Photoshop probably have a better image resizing algorithm than bilinear interpolation. Try Lanczos or Mitchell.

Comment: maybe, when resizing the image in photoshop you keep the aspect ratio (i.e. without distorting the pixels)

Comment: @AlexCohn No, most of the images were not square so I had to stretch them in height and fit them in 224x224 canvas. (aspect ratio was not kept.)